# How to fix getWritableDatabase() error in android studio?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using `SQLite` for the first time. I'm following some youtube tutorial for this. But I'm facing error with `getWritableDatabase()`.

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

if I add this line in `Mainactivity.java`, my app keeps stopping. If I remove this line, then my app runs but the database doesn't create.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

This is my Database class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "attendanceproject.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "TeacherInfo";
    private static final String ID = "_id";
    private static final String NAME ="name";
    private static final String EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String PHONE = "phone";
    private static final int VERSION_NAME = 3;
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NAME+" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,"+EMAIL+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+PASSWORD+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+PHONE+" VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL);";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION_NAME);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        try {

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Oncreate is Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR6Pi.png)

Comment: share your error logs plz.

Comment: Your _context_ is _null_

Comment: could you show us your logs?

Comment: I have added a image of error log in my question

Comment: always try to put your error using code(``) format rather than the image.

Comment: As  i mentioned _context_ is null

Comment: ok. Actually I'm new in stackoverflow too. So i don't know all rule. I'll remember this.

Comment: It's Ok. Welcome to the community. `Happy Coding`.

Comment: @AyeshaAnika Not an issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your `context` in `DatabaseHelper`. like the following.

```
private Context context;

public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION_NAME);
   this.context = context; // add this line to initialize your context.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to show a `Toast` with `Context` that is not initialised. First time in the try block and it throws, another time in the catch block and that exception then crashes the app.

Consider removing the try-catch altogether. If there is a problem creating the database, `onCreate()` should throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way.

create on separate java class for **DatabaseHandler**

```
package example.yourpackage;  

import android.content.ContentValues;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.database.Cursor;  
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;  
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; 

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {  
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbName";  
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "tableName";  
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";  
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";  
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number"

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {  
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
        //3rd argument to be passed is CursorFactory instance  
    }  

   @Override  
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {  
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("  
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"  
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";  
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);  
    }  

   // Upgrading database  
    @Override  
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
        // Drop older table if existed  
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);  

        // Create tables again  
        onCreate(db);  
    }  

    // code to add the new contact  
    void addContact(Contact contact) {  
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();  

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name  
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone  

        // Inserting Row  
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);  
        //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack  
        db.close(); // Closing database connection  
    } 
}
```

In your main activity **MainActivity**

```
@Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);  
}
```

Now you can check that the database is created.

> To view the data stored in sqlite in android studio.

Follow the following steps to view the database and its data stored in android sqlite:

1. Open File Explorer.
2. Go to data directory inside data directory.
3. Search for your application package name.
4. Inside your application package go to databases where you will found your database (contactsManager).
5. Save your database (contactsManager) anywhere you like.
6. Download any SqLite browser plugins or tool (in my case DB Browser for SQLite).
7. Launch DB Browser for SQLite and open your database (contactsManager).
8. Go to Browse Data -> select your table (contacts) you will see the data stored.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Why need this too much code? Issue was regarding only with _context_

Comment: I have given full database connection/creation and accessing example.

Comment: Code and answer should be respected to error and bug. I don't think it needs full code.

Comment: As i know that answer should be as per OP's question. Not for reputation only

Answer (score -1):

Based on the error, looks like your context is null.

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
}
```

If you want to see logging information use something like logcat, don't use a Toast.

Also,

I would use an ORM such as Room.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

The above article has a pretty good explanation.

The below has good examples.

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/BasicRxJavaSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/persistence

Comment: This should be comment!